# Good xpath but no result in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I wrote the following xpath :

```
//datas[child::node()//DataInfo/DataInfoItem[contains(@Value,'EA22')]]
```

applied to the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<Customer Modified="false">
    <datas>
        <FireData>
            <DataInfo>
                <DataInfoItem Name="place" Value="g5688"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="number" Value="EA22"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="use" Value="ice"/>
            </DataInfo>
            <DataHistorics>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-11-25T07:54:31" Type="0" visual="691.77"/>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-12-02T07:23:29" Type="0" visual="618.65"/>
            </DataHistorics>
            <FireDataData Previous="106256.71"/>
        </FireData>
    </datas>
</Customer>
<Customer Modified="false">
    <datas>
        <FireData>
            <DataInfo>
                <DataInfoItem Name="place" Value="g5678"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="number" Value="GH44"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="use" Value="ice"/>
            </DataInfo>
            <DataHistorics>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-11-25T07:54:31" Type="0" visual="691.77"/>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-12-02T07:23:29" Type="0" visual="618.65"/>
            </DataHistorics>
            <FireDataData Previous="106256.71"/>
        </FireData>
    </datas>
</Customer>
```

I tried several xpath tester online (http://www.xpathtester.com/, http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) and with Oxygen too,
and the xpath is all the time returning what I am looking for :

```
<datas>
        <FireData>
            <DataInfo>
                <DataInfoItem Name="place" Value="g5688"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="number" Value="EA22"/>
                <DataInfoItem Name="use" Value="ice"/>
            </DataInfo>
            <DataHistorics>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-11-25T07:54:31" Type="0" visual="691.77"/>
                <DataHistoric HistoDate="2013-12-02T07:23:29" Type="0" visual="618.65"/>
            </DataHistorics>
            <FireDataData Previous="106256.71"/>
        </FireData>
    </datas>
```

But if I did this in php, I get nothing :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(test.xml);
$data = $xml->xpath("//datas[child::node()//DataInfo/DataInfoItem[contains(@Value,'EA22')]]");
var_dump($data)
```

I really don't understand, I read in an other discussion that var_dump is not good to print the result of a xpath query, but I tried a lot of things and I don't think it's comming from there.

Anymone can help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Seems to work find in PHP with plain DOM: https://eval.in/86074

Comment: your code works fine with me: https://eval.in/86076 - error is probably not in the xpath-expression.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, in your example XML there's a `</root>` missing at the end, but I guess that's just a copy/paste error.

The problem in your code is that you didn't put the file name in quotation marks:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(test.xml);
```

If you do something like `echo hello;`, PHP tries to compensate by interpreting "hello" as string. In your case however what it does is interpreting this as *two* string: "test" and "xml" because `.` is the string concatenation operator. So it will try to open "testxml" (which is what you get if you put "test" and "xml" together) instead of "test.xml".

The fix would be:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
```

And then it works just fine for me.